# How to change the way Xamarin Studio formats code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm the kind of guy how writes my code like this

```
if(...)
{

}
```

but every time I do that Xamarin Studio automatically changes my code to this

```
if(...){

}
```

How do I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xamarin Studio's preferences, go to `Source Code` > `Code Formatting` > `C# source code`, and click the Edit button:

[image: C# formatting preferences]

From there you can customize basically everything. You can select the `Braces` category to customize brace formatting:

[image: Brace preferences]